# redissearch tag field fuzzy search

Tags: redis, redisearch

I want to perform fuzzy search in redissearch. Let's say I have "JEREMY,J" in tag field in the database. I want to find JEREM. I tried

```
FT.SEARCH employee "@FN_Tags:{JEREM}~0.2"
```

but it doesn't appear to work

Right now the only query that appears to work is processing only TEXT fields:

```
FT.SEARCH employee "@FN_Fuzzy:%JEREM%"
```

But trying to do so over tags results in a syntax error

```
FT.SEARCH employee "@FN_Tags:{%JEREM%}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuzzy search is not supported on tag fields, but you can use prefix search for tags.
From the [tag field documentation](https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/reference/tags/):

> Tags support prefix matching with the regular * character:

```
> FT.SEARCH idx "@tags:{ hell* }"
> FT.SEARCH idx "@tags:{ hello\\ w* }"
```

You can also use suffix (`*tag`) or “contains” (`*tag*`).
So for your case

```
> FT.SEARCH employee "@FN_Tags:{JEREM*}"
```

Should work.
Hope that helps.